Gradle build failed with "DexArchiveBuilderException" and "Cannot invoke 'String.length()' because 'string' is null"
I'm working on a React Native project using Gradle, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to build my app. The build fails with the following error message:

Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
250 actionable tasks: 57 executed, 193 up-to-date
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/mariomendoza/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/04074754fc70850f2ca5697a308d0095/transformed/jars/classes.jar
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/mariomendoza/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/04074754fc70850f2ca5697a308d0095/transformed/jars/classes.jar
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
...
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "string" is null
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexString.(DexString.java:27)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexItemFactory.createString(DexItemFactory.java:805)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarClassFileReader$CreateMethodVisitor.visitParameter(JarClassFileReader.java:622)
...
Additional Information:
I'm using Java 11 in my project.
React Native version: 0.61.5
Gradle version: 6.9
Steps I have tried to resolve the issue:
Cleaned the project and rebuilt it using ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew assembleRelease.
Deleted the .gradle and build directories and tried rebuilding.
Despite these steps, I still encounter the same error. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
